# Scroll a web page using Javascript whose scroll triggers at the middle of page

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, scroll, dom-events

I have encountered some websites which has footer at the bottom and scroll actually happens when I scroll to the area above footer.

To automatically scroll those pages, but the problem with my code currently is it goes at the bottom of the page, where I directly reach footer and hence the scroll trigger which is present just above the footer does not gets triggered.

Is there any way to achieve the same?

This is what I have tried currently which I am executing from the console:

```
(function() {
    var intervalObj = null;
    var retry = 0;
    var clickHandler = function() { 
        console.log("Clicked; stopping autoscroll");
        clearInterval(intervalObj);
        document.body.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    }
    function scrollDown() { 
        var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight,
            scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop,
            innerHeight = window.innerHeight,
            difference = (scrollHeight - scrollTop) - innerHeight

        if (difference > 0) { 
            window.scrollBy(0, difference);
            if (retry > 0) { 
                retry = 0;
            }
            console.log("scrolling down more");
        } else {
            if (retry >= 3) {
                console.log("reached bottom of page; stopping");
                clearInterval(intervalObj);
                document.body.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
            } else {
                console.log("[apparenty] hit bottom of page; retrying: " + (retry + 1));
                retry++;
            }
        }
    }

    document.body.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

    intervalObj = setInterval(scrollDown, 1000);

})()
```

There are many websites that has this feature, to test the same one of the website which you can try is

https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/indiranagar-restaurants

**Note :** The question similar to this does not answer how to scroll at some mid point of page instead it takes me directly to the footer, so this is not a duplicate

Comment: there is no such direct way in which u can achieve the same, just keep scrolling to the lenght of windows-footer length every time, that may work

Comment: Can you improve the clarity of this question? It's a little bit confusing, don't really understand what you want to achieve. Maybe add a descriptive example.

Comment: in simple words, first of all visit that website I mentioned, try scrolling it, you will find the data being loaded whenever you scroll. Now I just need to do the same using the javascript code.

Comment: The problem is my code works only when the scroll gets triggered when the user scrolls to the botttom but in my case scroll gets triggered at the middle above the footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although [Kumar Rishabh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13362939/kumar-rishabh) has already answered your question, I have another solution for this situation.

Set the domain to detect if the user scrolls to the domain.
The effect just like the website you povider . https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/indiranagar-restaurants

**I do some simple example for you with pure Javascript.**

#### Fragment core code:

```
      // Here is domain to detect if user scroll into.
      if (
        triggerDomain.getBoundingClientRect().top < window.innerHeight &&
        triggerDomain.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0
      ) {
        if (getMore === false) {
          getMore = true
          // Do something you want here ....
          console.info('got more !!')
```

#### Full code sample, check code snippet:

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("rootDiv");
const triggerDomain = document.getElementById("triggerDomain");

let getMore = false;

function detectScrollIntoDomain() {
  // Here is domain to detect if user scroll into.
  if (
    triggerDomain.getBoundingClientRect().top < window.innerHeight &&
    triggerDomain.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0
  ) {
    if (getMore === false) {
      getMore = true;
      // Do something you want here ....
      console.info("got more !!");
      setTimeout(() => {
        let currentScrollTop = rootElement.scrollTop;
        for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
          let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
          let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
          let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
          const contentElement = document.getElementById("content");
          const card = document.createElement("div");
          card.className = "contentCard";
          card.style.backgroundColor = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
          contentElement.appendChild(card);
        }
        rootElement.scrollTo(0, currentScrollTop);
        // Don't forget to set flag to `false`.
        getMore = false;
      }, 200);
    }
  }
}

rootElement.addEventListener("scroll", detectScrollIntoDomain, {
  passive: true
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: aliceblue;
}

#rootDiv {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
}

#content div:first-child {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#triggerDomain {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  outline: 1px dashed rgb(3, 25, 119);
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    rgba(46, 45, 45, 0.3) 0,
    rgba(46, 45, 45, 0.3) 10px,
    rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.3) 10px,
    rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.3) 20px
  );
}

#footer {
  height: 180%;
  background-color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
}

.contentCard {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/styles.css"
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="rootDiv">
      <div id="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div>
          <h2>Content</h2>
          <h2>Scroll down to get more cards.</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="triggerDomain">
          <h2>Trigger domain</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Hope to help you !**

Answer (score 2):

Logic is to retain to the middle of the Scroller unless the page is completely loaded. We can tweak the code a little to achieve the last position of scroller. Try this:

```js
 var scrollHeight = 0,
    newScrollHeight;
  do {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight / 2);
    newScrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight / 2;
    if (newScrollHeight == scrollHeight) {
      break;
    } else {
      scrollHeight = newScrollHeight;
    }
  } while (true);
```

Comment: OP asked for a Javascript code and not Java code

Comment: Now its Javascript code.

Comment: does not work scrolls only once

Comment: I am not great with Javascript. But yes you may need to fix the loop